# Can not find the methods at different Paypal Rest API classes

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, paypal

I have downloaded Paypal-Java-SDK-Master and built it with the Gradle plugin in Eclipse. I made a jar-archive of the classes and included it in my project. And I copied some code from somewhere. Below is an extract:
The problem is that the methods called on the Amount, Payer and all the other classes do not exist. Inspection of the java-files confirms this. Have I downloaded and installed the wrong archive or is the example to old? 
Is there someone that can give me some help?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.paypal.api.payments.Amount;
import com.paypal.api.payments.Payer;
import com.paypal.api.payments.Payment;
import com.paypal.api.payments.RedirectUrls;
import com.paypal.api.payments.Transaction;
import com.paypal.base.rest.APIContext;
import com.paypal.base.rest.PayPalRESTException;

public class JavaSampleOne {
    String clientId = "some id I not want to share";
    String clientSecret = "some id I not want to share";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Amount amount = new Amount();
    amount.setCurrency("USD");
    amount.setTotal("1.00");

    Transaction transaction = new Transaction();
    transaction.setAmount(amount);
    List<Transaction> transactions = new ArrayList<Transaction>();
    transactions.add(transaction);

    Payer payer = new Payer();
    payer.setPaymentMethod("paypal");
```

I changed to implementation in the gradle.build file. When I refreshed the project I got this error:[Errormessage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEh39.png)
This is my file structure: [Filestructure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXsn4.png)
This is how it looks like in Eclipse navigator: [Eclipse navigator projects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czSa6.png)
I choosed Wrapper when I imported the project.

Comment: I just built the methods I lacked, compiled and run this file. But, then I missed something called Lombok. The Paypal Rest Api obviously is dependent upon this, and that is the reason why I could not find the methods, because they should be created on-the-fly with Lombok.
 My Gradle import left me with several projects called rest-api, rest-api-sample and rest-api-sdk.
The javafile I've put in another project called ProjectPlanner. So the problem I have is connected to the compilation and import of the Paypal-java-sdk. And I have no idea on how to do this correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

delete (or move) the local `jar` and add this to your `build.gradle`:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

     // paypal-core should be automatically fetched
     // implementation "com.paypal.sdk:paypal-core:1.7.2"

     // that's the one you actually may need
     implementation "com.paypal.sdk:rest-api-sdk:1.14.0"
}
```

then synchronize the Gradle project, in order to fetch the dependencies.

there are some more artifacts available for [com.paypal.sdk](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.paypal.sdk).

Comment: I tried to do as you suggest. I got another error, because I do not have the api, I think.

Comment: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/anne/PayPal-Java-SDK-master/build.gradle' line: 8

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'rest-api'.
> Could not find method api() for arguments [com.paypal.sdk:rest-api-sdk:1.14.0] on org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler_Decorated@6982bcb.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Comment: Now I've downloaded the library from the link you posted.

Comment: have downgraded the syntax ... because api might either be newer or Android specific.

Comment: I suddenly understood that all the classes I needed were available in a binary format in the artifacts you pointed out. Then I didn't need to use Gradle to compile the source, as I thougth I had to. Then the solution is really simple. I just include the binaries into my project. But thank you very much for your help, Martin Zeitler. I will accept your answer if I can figure out how.

Comment: @AnneHeleneHolmen one does not need to add those jars to the project, when adding them as dependencies, to be fetched (alike this one may also know of newer versions). local dependencies can be included with `implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')`

Comment: Is this something I should put in gradle.build ? I think I must find a beginners guide to Gradle if I'm going to use Gradle. Are there more advantages with Gradle than fetching up-to-date libraries when I need them?

Comment: @AnneHeleneHolmen Gradle is quite versatile and can not only be configured, but also scripted: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide.html

Comment: Thank you very much fro the link, Martin Zeitler.